# The POST method is not supported for this route

Tags: php, laravel

Начал учить laravel, и наткнулся на странную вещь.

Есть вот такой blade шаблон:

```
<body>
<form action="/posts/store/" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="text">
    @csrf
    <input type="submit">

</form>
</body>
```

Route вот такой:

```
Route::resource('posts', '\App\Http\Controllers\PostController');
```

Сделал отображение записей, перешёл к добавлению, и тут выпадаю всегда в:

```
The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE.
```

Но если  смотреть через `php artisan route:list`, то поддерживается только POST

[image: Метод POST]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы форму сабмитите по "/posts/store/", а в роуте ясно написано, что для ресурсного контроллера прописан путь "posts".
Соответственно решение для вас либо:

1. Меняете в форме экшн на правильный "/posts":

   `form action="/posts"`
2. Не заморачиваетесь с адресами (которые, кстати могут и поменяться), а используете имена (у вас они прописаны в роутах):

   `form action="{{ route('posts.store') }}"`